# How to download content of /storage/emulated/0/android/data/ with Terminal (OSX)

Tags: android, macos, terminal, adb

I want to download the content of `/storage/emulated/0/android/data/com.xxxx.myapp` as zip file to my Mac download folder.

1. I connect my Android phone with USB to my Mac
2. I open terminal
3. I run `adb shell`
4. I run `cd /storage/emulated/0/android/data`

Now, how to zip and download `com.xxxx.myapp` folder to my Mac download folder?

Or, how to copy `com.xxxx.myapp` folder to my Mac download folder?

When I run `adb shell`, the prompt becomes `a50:/ $` in Terminal.

If I do `cp com.xxxx.myapp /Users/my_user/Downloads` I get

```
cp: Skipped dir '/Users/my_user/Downloads': No such file or directory'.
```

Comment: To close voters: despite _generally_ pulling data off an Android phone being a general computing task, the specific task of dumping your own app's data directory is certainly programming-related, and therefore on-topic here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`adb pull`](https://adbshell.com/commands/adb-pull).

(Running `cp` on the phone can't work because your Mac's folders won't exist on the phone. Plus, you forgot `-R`.)

How to zip: You can create a tarball and save it in `/data/local/tmp` or some other location you have write access to, by using a regular `tar` command on the phone:

```sh
tar -czf /data/local/tmp/archive.tgz com.xxxx.myapp
```

Then, **exit the ADB shell** and run an `adb pull` command on the host instead:

```sh
adb pull /data/local/tmp/archive.tgz ~/Downloads/
```

You can also just pull the whole folder without compressing it first:

```sh
adb pull /storage/emulated/0/android/data/com.xxxx.myapp ~/Downloads/
```

Comment: Thank you so much ! That's absolutely brillant. Used adb pull /storage/emulated/0/android/data/com.xxxx.myapp ~/Downloads/ Works like a charm :)